# Simple HTML Dom: Select and count child element (.eq function to Simple HTML Dom)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I can't seem to translate the DOM language to the Simple HTML DOM language. This is the correct solution which is on the Google Chrome console:

```
$('div.row.player-sidebar-item', 0).children().eq(17).children().length;
//console answer: 4
```

and hereby the correct answer, but I need it to be done with Simple HTML DOM and can't find any information for it. This code is also returning the information I need:

```
$('div.col-xs-5.player-sidebar-value', 0).eq(4).children().length;
//console answer: 4
```

I don't know how I can do this in Simple HTML DOM and thus my code until now:

```
$countwf = count($futhead->find('div.row.player-sidebar-item', 0)->childNodes(17));
```

and that is the best I can get there, I don't know how to do this better. 
I hope someone can help me.

**================ FIRST UPDATE ================**

After the first comment, I have tried this:

```
echo $countwf = count($futhead->find('div[class=col-xs-5 player-sidebar-value]', 0)->childNodes(4)->children());
```

this is not working,

```
echo $countwf = count($futhead->find('div[class=row player-sidebar-item]', 0)->childNodes(17)->children());
```

is not working either.

**================ FINAL UPDATE ================**

After an hour researching and just trying I found the right answer!

```
echo $countwf = count($futhead->find('div[class=col-xs-5 player-sidebar-value]', 4)->children());
```

thanks for your help, I hope that people in the future benefit from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not counting the children of node 17, you need to call `->children()`

```
$countwf = count($futhead->find('div.row.player-sidebar-item', 0)->childNodes(17)->children());
```

Comment: hi Barmar, I have tried your solution but if I try this: `echo $countwf = count($futhead->find('div[class=col-xs-5 player-sidebar-value]', 0)->childNodes(5)->children());` I don't get the 4. This code should be the same as: `$('div.col-xs-5.player-sidebar-value', 0).eq(5).children().length;`